# Aggregate Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate, alter-table

I try to aggregate my t1:

| Date | Name | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-29 | Erwin | 50 |
| 2021-08-29 | Erwin | 60 |
| 2021-08-30 | Erwin | 35 |
| 2021-08-30 | Igor | 20 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: |

And I want to update this table to:

| Date | Name | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-29 | Erwin | 110 |
| 2021-08-30 | Erwin | 35 |
| 2021-08-30 | Igor | 20 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: |

I dont want to select this query like
(Select Date, Name, sum(cost) From t1
Group by date, Name) I want to update the table. Something like "Update" or "Alter table".
I tried:
Update t1
Set cost = sum(cost)
Group by date, Name; but it didnt work.

Can you help me pls?

Thanks :)

Comment: Updating the table doesn't change the number of rows.  You would need to do an update and delete.

Answer (score 0):

bigquery seems to support `MERGE`, but I'm not sure if this will work when the source and target table are the same.  I'm assuming you have a primary key (`pk`) or something similar you can use to identify each row in the table uniquely.  Try this:

```
MERGE INTO test
USING (
          SELECT xdate, name
               , SUM(cost) AS total
               , MIN(pk)   AS pk
            FROM test
           GROUP BY name, xdate
      ) AS source
   ON test.xdate = source.xdate
  AND test.name  = source.name

WHEN MATCHED AND test.pk = source.pk THEN
   UPDATE
      SET test.cost = source.total
WHEN MATCHED AND test.pk <> source.pk THEN
   DELETE
;
```

Here's a test case with oracle (don't have bigquery access), just to show an example of how this would work. Syntax is slightly different:

```
MERGE INTO test
USING (
          SELECT xdate, name
               , SUM(cost) AS total
               , MIN(pk)   AS pk
            FROM test
           GROUP BY name, xdate
      ) source
   ON (test.xdate = source.xdate
  AND test.name   = source.name
  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET test.cost = source.total
   DELETE WHERE (test.pk    <> source.pk)
;
```

The result:

[image]

[The oracle test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30df869eecb54bce633ddd14865e15e9)